# Laravel Route Controller issue

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I am trying to add a new route to my application and can't seem to get it to work.  I keep getting a 404 error.  It looks like the physical path is looking at the wrong directory.  Currently looking at D:\Web\FormMapper\blog\public\forms but should be looking at D:\Web\FormMapper\blog\resources\view\layout\pages\forms.blade.php

My request URL:

```
http://localhost/FormMapper/           /works fine
http://localhost/FormMapper/forms      /doesn't work
http://localhost/FormMapper/forms.php  /No input file specified.
```

my FormsController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FormsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('layouts.pages.forms');
    }
}
```

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts/pages/login');
});
Route::get('/forms', 'FormsController@index');
```

My folder structure looks like this:
[image]

My config/view.php

```
return [
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'),
],

'compiled' => env(
    'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
    realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
),
];
```

Comment: Could you add your config/view.php file ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracking digging deeper I determined that the issue was that IIS requires URL rewrite rules in place for Laravel to work properly. The index.php and '/' route would work b/c it was the default page but any other pages wouldn't. To test this I used the

```
php artisan serve
```

approach to it. and everything worked properly.  Unfortunately I am unable to do this in production so I needed to get it to work with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

you must use dot for this. In your controller change to this:

```
return view('layouts.pages.forms');
```

Comment: Yes, same issue.  I have also updated the question to see if that was part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your route only needs to return a view, you may use the `Route::view` method. Like the redirect method, this method provides a simple shortcut so that you do not have to define a full route or controller. The view method accepts a URI as its first argument and a view name as its second argument. In addition, you may provide an array of data to pass to the view as an optional third argument:

```
Route::view('/', 'layouts.pages.login');

Route::view('/forms', 'layouts.pages.forms', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#view-routes)

Comment: This doesn't work either.  I am starting to think, something else is the issue.